# Mod_rewrite ignoring condition

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Apache seems to ignore the condition below.  I am trying to make sure that if the request URI has the word sitemap in it, to not do the Rewrite rule.  Example:

http://www.mysites.com/sitemap or http://www.mysites.com/sitemap/users/sitemap1.gz

```
<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot|google-structured-data-testing-tool|semrushbot|applebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|ahrefsbot|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest\/0\.|pinterestbot|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator|whatsapp [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff|\.svg))
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap(/|$)

    RewriteRule ^(index\.html|index\.php)?(.*) https://service.prerender.io/%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [P,L]
</IfModule>
```

Apache just seems to ignore this and does the proxy request.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my bad:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap(/|$)
```

Should have been:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^sitemap
```